# Converting a stream of Mono to Flux

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, project-reactor

I have a REST controller method that receives a list of IDs via path variable:

```
@GetMapping("/api/test/{ids}")
fun findAllByIds(@PathVariable ids: Array<String>) = ...
```

From the repository, I would like to send a `Flux` of the matching objects based on the ids. What is the base way to do this. I can do a filter based operation on `findAll()` or is there a better way of handling this?

```
@GetMapping("/api/test/{ids}")
fun findAllByIds(@PathVariable ids: Array<String>) = service.findAll()
    .filter { ids.contains(testObject.id) }
```

Comment: If you really have no choice but to use`findAll()` for whatever reason, then I don't think you can do any better - but that seems unlikely to me. What type is `service`? If it's some kind of data repository, then it's almost certainly going to be more efficient to implement a `findByIds()` method or similar and do your filtering at the data level, rather than pulling it all into a `Flux` and filtering afterwards. (Side point, I'm not sure where the title comes into this - we don't seem to be dealing with `Mono` here at all, unless I'm missing something?)

Comment: @MichaelBerry Thanks for your comment. I have a method `findById(...)`. This returns `Mono<Test>`. I was hoping to iterate over the the `Array<String>` and getting a "List" of `Mono` and then changing it to `Flux`. I guess the approach mentioned by you makes more sense - creating a method in the `Repository` that returns a `Flux<Test>` objects.

Comment: If you want to go that way and have an array of `Mono`s from multiple `findById()` calls then you can just do [Flux.concat()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concat-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-), passing that array in as the varargs argument. But yes, definitely better to implement a `findByIds()` method on your data layer if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the *best* method here would be to add a `findByIds(...)` method to your data layer, so it can just return the values you need in a single query / request. That's almost certainly going to be much more efficient than manipulating the data afterwards.

If you can't do that, then you have two options:

- Call `findById()` in a loop to obtain a `List<Mono>` or `Mono[]`, then just use the static [`Flux.concat()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-) method to turn that into a `Flux`;
- Call `findAll()` and then filter as you're doing in your question.

If you have to use one of the above, which is more efficient depends on your scenario - in the case where there's loads of IDs being passed in, and the complete set returned by `findAll()` is relatively small, then calling `findAll()` and filtering would probably be best.

If on the other hand, there's relatively few IDs being passed in, and the complete set of data is huge, then you're better calling `findById()` in a loop.

To reiterate however - both of the above approaches are inferior to handling this on the data layer.

Comment: Would concatinating a `Mono[]` or `List<Mono>` be blocking? The idea of the whole exercise was to use **Reactive** paradigm?

Comment: @Prashant It'll just subscribe to each mono in turn - it's not blocking at all. (I'd give a clear warning if it was, because as you say, that defeats the point of using reactor in the first place.)

Comment: Nice! Thanks Michael for your help. It looks like I will have to spend some more time going through the documentation.

Comment: @Prashant No problem. Reactor is generally very clear when something blocks - it'll often have `block` in its method name, and (in all cases I can find) always mentions it in the methods Javadoc, usually in bold! If it doesn't, you can safely assume it won't block.